# Visual Studio: Unable to launch docker asp.net app ssl error

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to build the default app that is created when doing a `dotnet new mvc` command and then adding docker support. I keep on getting the following error:
[image: Unable to install the ASP.NET Core development certtificate tool (dev-certs)]

The app is running in docker (I can see it in kitematics), I just can't seem to connect to it.

Comment: What is your VS version? Try to upgrade to latest version. What is .net core sdk? Try to install .net core sdk 2.1.

Comment: I'm running VS2017 (15.8.9) and the following .net sdk's:
1.1.10,
1.1.11,
2.1.202,
2.1.300,
2.1.302,
2.1.400,
2.1.401,
2.1.402,
2.1.403,
2.2.100